# Changing background image of a view

Tags: ios

I'm using the current code to change the background image, but the problem is the when you press the button, the image is changed only for the current view. There are two views in the app (Main View and `Settings` View. What I want to achieve is to change background only for the main view when the button is pressed. How can I do this?

Here is the code currently:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
//Change background image..................................................
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"picture7.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//..........................................................................
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will only change Background of main view i-e file owner's view.

If you want to change specific view's background color programmatically then you should write

```
[self.settingsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"default.png"]]];
```

you can do same from interface builder as well if nothing dynamic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Shahab. I cannot make it work, so I`ll do something different instead. I`ll add different views for every background. I`ll create it this way even dough it may make the app little bit bigger.